# PyAudio: Multichannel Sound

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm working on an experiment concerned with spatial sound perception. In this experiment, different sounds should be simultaneously presented from up to eight speakers. For this purpose, I would like to create a Python code for OS X (10.10.5) can read from a multichannel sound file and send each channel of this sound file to a designated speaker (via an appropriate hardware device).

I came across a rather convenient solution for the "present from multiple speakers"-part of the problem: Following this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psychopy-users/6iao-XbWxag), it can be easily done for mono/stereo files by adding more entries to the *channel_map* in *PyAudio*. The (slightly modified) code looks like this:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

chunk = 4096

PyAudio = pyaudio.PyAudio

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(-1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

p = PyAudio()

channel_map = (0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

try:
stream_info = pyaudio.PaMacCoreStreamInfo(
flags=pyaudio.PaMacCoreStreamInfo.paMacCorePlayNice, # default
channel_map=channel_map)
except AttributeError:
print("Sorry, couldn't find PaMacCoreStreamInfo. Make sure that "
"you're running on Mac OS X.")
sys.exit(-1)

print("Stream Info Flags:", stream_info.get_flags())
print("Stream Info Channel Map:", stream_info.get_channel_map())
print("channels",wf.getnchannels())

print('sample width',wf.getsampwidth())

stream = p.open(
format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
channels=wf.getnchannels(),
rate=wf.getframerate(),
output=True,
output_host_api_specific_stream_info=stream_info)

data = wf.readframes(chunk)

while data != '':
stream.write(data)
data = wf.readframes(chunk)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

However, I wonder whether this also works with multichannel sound files in *PyAudio*? Is it possible to read from a multichannel (i.e 8-channel) sound file and to send specific channels to different output devices (e.g. speakers) with PyAudio?

If yes, can someone provide an example of how it can be done? I don't mind digging some more into libraries/modules but providing an example for the code in question would help me (as a novice) a lot.

If PyAudio is not the right choice, I would really appreciate any further recommendations/ideas/comments on how it can be done.

Thanks a lot!

Malte